# High level overview of ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've spent a lot of time working in Django, and have grokked the framework well enough that I have started replacing the original components (view engine, etc.) with my own custom components and the sky hasn't fallen down.

I've been looking at ASP.NET MVC, and been quite interested (I really like C#/F#) but so far have learned... just about nothing. I've been digging through http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 without much success. I suppose my main questions would be:

- What are the main moving parts in a typical workflow? Let's say a request comes in. Who takes it, does stuff, and passes it on to who else? In Django, for example, a request goes through the URL Mapper, Middleware, goes to a controller, which may dig through some models (via explicit function calls) and get some data, pass it into a template (also via an explicit function call) to be rendered and pass it back.
- What kind of client-server coupling is there? For example, in many frameworks there is a explicit coupling of each HTML-form with a serverside-validator, with a model, with a database table, such that client side validation code is automatically generated. Another example is Quora's Livenode, which explicitly links client-side HTML components with their dependencies in the model, allowing changes in the database to propagate and automagically update client-side code.

Comment: I would suggest you get a good book on MVC to get both a better overview and a deep dive on some of the areas of the framework. I recommend "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework" by Sanderson http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no better answer to your first question than ASP.NET MVC Pipeline :

http://www.simple-talk.com/content/file.ashx?file=6068

explained in more detail here :

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/an-introduction-to-asp.net-mvc-extensibility/

To your second question : answer is **none**. ASP.NET application dont even have to render HTML output, you can write your own viewengine to give any representation of the data, not consumed by browser, but any http (REST) capable device. The only things you can consider as coupling "conventions" (for model binding for example), but they can be replaced and extended in any way you like.

Answer (score 1):

> What kind of client-server coupling is there?

As rouen said, none.

I am not familiar with Django, but unlike other MVC frameworks (including Rails) ASP.NET MVC is very skinny in that it only implements Views and Controllers of the traditional MVC pattern. You are pretty much on your own for the model part. That means there is no built-in support for database creation, ORM, et cetera.

ASP.NET MVC does implement a bunch of plumbing to route requests to the appropriate controllers and even some binding of parameters (e.g. query string parameters, form values) when instantiating controllers but *this binding is not to a full blown model*. The binding in this context is usually either single values or "viewModels"

ASP.NET MVC also implements the plumbing to select the right view to render.

Comment: Given what you said, is it normal for peopple to plug in lots of their own components (e.g. ORM, CSRF validation, templating engine, etc.) from elsewhere? In contrast other frameworks I used (rails, django) come with a ton of that sort of functionality built in

Comment: Most people use the built-in view engine Razor for views (which is very good.) For ORM you are on your own, although there are several good components out there (NHibernate, EF, LLBLGen) that you'll need to evaluate.